# generate combinations from list of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

generate all combinations from list of numbers,the combinations can be pair of two numbers

example 1 :  list of 2 numbers [1,2]

```
[
[[1],[2]],
[[1,2]]
]
```

example 2 :  list of 3 numbers [1,2,3]

```
[
[[1], [2], [3]],
[[1], [2, 3]],
[[1, 3], [2]],
[[1, 2], [3]]
]
```

example 3 :  list of 4 numbers [1,2,3,4]

```
[
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]],
[[1], [2, 4], [3]],
[[1], [2, 3], [4]],
[[1, 4], [2], [3]],
[[1, 3], [2], [4]],
[[1, 2], [3], [4]],
[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
[[1, 3], [2, 4]],
[[1, 4], [2, 3]]
]
```

The current implementation works but it is slow for list of 10 numbers

```
from itertools import combinations
def get_all_order_combinations(nums, first=True):
    if first and len(nums) == 1:
        return [[[nums[0]]]]
    if len(nums) == 2:
        nums.sort()
        return [
            [[nums[0]], [nums[1]]],
            [[nums[0], nums[1]]]
        ]
    else:
        all_results = []
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            temp_list = list(nums)
            del temp_list[i]
            current_num = nums[i]
            results = get_all_order_combinations(temp_list, False)
            results = [[[current_num]]+result for result in results]
            for result in results:
                result.sort()
                if result not in all_results:
                    all_results.append(result)
        if len(nums) >= 4:
            for comb in combinations(nums, 2):
                comb = list(comb)
                results = get_all_order_combinations(
                    [n for n in nums if n not in comb]
                    ,False
                )
                results = [[comb]+result for result in results]
                for result in results:
                    result.sort()
                    if result not in all_results:
                        all_results.append(result)
        return all_results
```

an old implementation that works only for 5 numbers

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce 

def _is_unique(items):
    return len(items) == len(set(items))


def _is_valid(items, ids_len):
    if _is_unique(items):
        if ids_len == len(items):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


def _generate_combinations(combs, ids):
    all_combinations = []
    ids_len = len(ids)
    for i in range(1, len(combs)+1):
        if i > ids_len:
            break
        if i == ids_len:
            all_combinations += [[[id] for id in ids]]
            continue
        if i == 1:
            if ids_len == 2:
                all_combinations += [[ids]]
            continue

        comb = combinations(combs, i)
        all_combinations += list(comb)  

    all_combinations = [list(c) for c in all_combinations if _is_valid(
        reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, c), ids_len)]
    return all_combinations


def _generate_initial_combinations(ids):
    all_combinations = []
    for i in range(1, 3):
        comb = combinations(ids, i)
        all_combinations += list(comb)
    all_combinations = [list(c) for c in all_combinations]
    return all_combinations


def get_all_order_combination_old(ids_list):
    combs = _generate_initial_combinations(ids_list)
    results = _generate_combinations(combs, ids_list)
    return results
```

Comment: Example 2: I suspect you lack [1, 2, 3].

Comment: Also, it seems your aim is to generate so called partitions of a set.

Comment: the way we write [1,2,3] is [[1],[2],[3]]

Comment: (I guess coderodde intended [[1, 2, 3]]: partition into one triple.)

Comment: *Specification by examples* is almost as bad as *specification by (old) undocumented code*.  

Does *ordered partitions into singletons and pairs* fit the bill?

Comment: @greybeard You are correct. Im in fact meant [[1, 2, 3]].

Comment: `[[[1, 3], [2]], [[1, 2], [3]]].sort()` yields [[[1, 2], [3]], [[1, 3], [2]]]: What is the actual ordering requirement?

Comment: See also: [split a list in pairs and unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30007067)

Comment: Do or don't you want the *old implementation* subject to review?

Answer (score 1):

What should be bogging this down is generating equivalent partitions more than once (and checking for duplicates) -
a first improvement was to add a `start` parameter to the recursive function, set to `i` in the first/*shorten by 1* loop.
(The next one may be *dynamic programming*/*function result caching*.)